# Why Is this Image Not loading Into my Xamarin Mobile App

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So This is the code that I have to generate an Image and its Size. whenever I run this code The Image doesn't come up. the icon.png is in my Android Resources file in each of the subfolders, it is one of the pre installed images so it should be able to find the image and display it. I have tried to put the full path into the File = "" section but That does not work either how can I get this image to display?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;

namespace PlatformBitmaps
{
   


public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        Image image = new Image
        {
            Source = new FileImageSource { File = "icon.png" }
        };
        

        Label label = new Label
        {
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };

        image.SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            label.Text = string.Format("Rendered size = {0} x {1}",
                image.Width, image.Height);
        };

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                image, label
            }
        };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Android - Place images in the Resources/drawable directory with Build Action

Comment: Okay so I didn't realize that it had to be in the drawable folder itself thank you that fixed it.